# Are people in Narak (hell) tortured and left alone ? Or Do they have companionship of other hell-dwellers?

Tags: hell

What happens in Narak (hell)?

Are people in hell left alone in solitary and tortured?

Or do they have the companionship of other dwellers of hell?